# Can I specify an operator or other syntactic literal within a macro input?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

First, I know this is not a good use of macros but I'm learning what I can do.

I have a struct `Rational`:

```
pub struct Rational{
    pub n: i128,
    pub d : i128
}
```

I have a macro that builds these:

```
macro_rules! rat{
    ($n : expr,  $d : expr) => {
        Rational{n : $n,d:  $d}
    }
}
```

The syntax for calling that macro looks like : `rat!(1, 3)`. I would like it to visually show a fractional format, so you would call it like `rat!(1 / 3)` instead, and the macro would parse that expression to yield the same result. (Note that if it first evaluates `1/3`, even as a float type, it will not exactly correspond as `1/3` does not correspond exactly to any float.)

I'm hoping there's some syntax like:

```
macro_rules! rat{
    ($n : expr `/` $d : expr) => {
        Rational{n : $n,d:  $d}
    }
}
```

where I can specify syntax to be used in the call. (That attempt does not compile, of course.)

Again, obviously this is silly and an X/Y problem and all that. For context, I'm considering building an equation wrangling system, and at some point I'd like to be able to parse things from a math-y syntax, which might actually justify the use of macros. This is just a baby step.

Does such a thing exist using declarative macros?
If not, is it possible with procedural macros?
Finally, I know that in Scala macros there would be no way to make that work for literal values, because the expression `1/3` would be resolved so early in the compilation process the AST would be gone by the time even macros are called. Is that also the case in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `/` token directly in the rule:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rational{
    n: i128,
    d: i128
}

macro_rules! rat {
    ($n:literal / $d:literal) => {
        Rational { n: $n, d: $d }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("rat!(1 / 3) = {:?}", rat!(1 / 3));
}
```

```
rat!(1 / 3) = Rational { n: 1, d: 3 }
```

However, notice I have changed the arguments from `expr` to `literal`. Your question seems to imply this is fine for your use-case, but I bring it up because at least the first parameter `$n` cannot be an `expr`. It would cause a parsing ambiguity because `/` is a valid continuation of an expression and Rust simply doesn't allow `/` as a separator after a `expr`. And this goes for *all* operators; from the [follow-set ambiguity restrictions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#follow-set-ambiguity-restrictions), only `=>`, `,`, or `;` may follow an `expr`.

If you do want to allow any `expr`, a common trick is to require parenthesis:

```
macro_rules! rat {
    ($n:literal / $d:expr) => {
        Rational { n: $n, d: $d }
    };
    (($n:expr) / $d:expr) => {
        Rational { n: $n, d: $d }
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("rat!(1 / 3) = {:?}", rat!(1 / 3));
    println!("rat!((1 + 2) / 3) = {:?}", rat!((1 + 2) / 3));
}
```

Comment: Interesting - is there any way around that, to let me use generic exprs? Maybe wrap them in parens in the macro rule or something? (Confirmed that that works, wondering if there's something lighter syntactically, or ideally just in the macro definition)

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes, requiring parens is a common workaround. I've added that to the answer. I don't think there's really a different solution beyond not using `/` or writing a procedural macro and sorting out the ambiguity yourself (which I wouldn't advise).